# Rails server fails to start with NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I’m using Windows 7 and I had no problem using `rails server` up to a few hours ago. When I try to run it, I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it seems like this was another app that you just copied over. the names are different demoapp and assignment. change the name in environment.rb

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this was another app that you just copied over. The names are different: `demoapp` and `assignment2`. You can change the name in `config/environment.rb`.

Comment: You just copied Sam D's comment into your answer.

Comment: @SampritiPanda what are you talking about? I just wanted to help by answering the question.

Comment: See the first comment on this question and compare it with your answer and you'll understand.

Comment: whatever. I'm here to help people and solve problems.